# Count of a value in consecutive timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

```
Hour              Site
01/08/2020 00:00    A
01/08/2020 00:00    B
01/08/2020 00:00    C
01/08/2020 00:00    D
01/08/2020 01:00    A
01/08/2020 01:00    B
01/08/2020 01:00    E
01/08/2020 01:00    F
01/08/2020 02:00    A
01/08/2020 02:00    E
01/08/2020 03:00    C
01/08/2020 03:00    G
 …..    
01/08/2020 04:00    x
01/08/2020 04:00    s

 …..    

01/08/2020 23:00    G
02/08/2020 00:00    G
```

I have a dataframe like above. I want to count how many times a site comes in consecutive hours & start and end timestamp. wheres in each hour there are multiple sites. 
For example site A appears in in 3 consecutive timestamp, then again in one timestamp.
I want an output like below, or in more effective format.

```
Hour              Site count    period_start    Period_end
01/08/2020 00:00    A   3   01/08/2020 00:00    01/08/2020 03:00
01/08/2020 00:00    B   2   01/08/2020 00:00    01/08/2020 01:00
01/08/2020 00:00    C   1   ….. …
01/08/2020 00:00    D   1   ….  ….
01/08/2020 01:00    A   3   01/08/2020 00:00    01/08/2020 03:00
01/08/2020 01:00    B   2   ….  ….
01/08/2020 01:00    E   2   ….  ….
01/08/2020 01:00    F   1   ….  ….
01/08/2020 02:00    A   3   01/08/2020 00:00    01/08/2020 03:00
01/08/2020 02:00    E   2   ….  ….
01/08/2020 03:00    C   1   ….  ….
01/08/2020 03:00    G   1   ….  ….
 …..            ….  ….
01/08/2020 04:00    x   1   01/08/2020 04:00    01/08/2020 04:00
01/08/2020 04:00    s   1   ….  ….
            ….  ….
 …..            ….  ….
            ….  ….
01/08/2020 23:00    G   2   ….  ….
02/08/2020 00:00    G   2   ….  ….
```

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're here for free code without trying it yourself first. This is not how Stackoverflow works. Please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and try to start programming what you want to achieve first, if you come across any problems, then we are here to help.

Comment: I don't understand... why count of site A is 3? It is 00:00,00:01,00:02 AND 00:04.

Comment: @funie200 understood, I will add my version

Comment: I added an answer, please check it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from defining 2 functions:

```
def cnt(grp):
    hr = grp.Hour
    return grp.assign(count=hr.size, period_start=hr.iloc[0], period_end=hr.iloc[-1])

def fn(grp):
    gr = grp.groupby((grp.Hour - grp.Hour.shift()).gt(pd.Timedelta('1H')).cumsum())
    return gr.apply(cnt)
```

Then group and apply it:

```
df.groupby('Site').apply(fn).reset_index(level=[0, 1], drop=True).sort_index()
```

You should start reading of the code from the end.

The first step is to group by *Site* (the first level of grouping)
and apply *fn* to each group.
For the time being skip the rest of this instruction.

Then *fn* function performs the second level grouping.
The idea is to divide the source (first level) group into groups of
rows for consecutive hours.

To each (second level) group *cnt* function is applied.
Its result is the source group with added *count*, *period_start* and
*period_end* columns.

And now there is time to look at the (skipped) part of the first instruction.
The *groupby(...).apply(...)* part generates the following result (for brevity
I included only result for *Site* == *A* and *B*.

```
                            Hour Site  count        period_start           period_end
Site Hour                                                                            
A    0    0  2020-08-01 00:00:00    A      3 2020-08-01 00:00:00  2020-08-01 02:00:00
          4  2020-08-01 01:00:00    A      3 2020-08-01 00:00:00  2020-08-01 02:00:00
          8  2020-08-01 02:00:00    A      3 2020-08-01 00:00:00  2020-08-01 02:00:00
     1    12 2020-08-01 04:00:00    A      2 2020-08-01 04:00:00  2020-08-01 05:00:00
          14 2020-08-01 05:00:00    A      2 2020-08-01 04:00:00  2020-08-01 05:00:00
     2    15 2020-08-01 08:00:00    A      1 2020-08-01 08:00:00  2020-08-01 08:00:00
B    0    1  2020-08-01 00:00:00    B      2 2020-08-01 00:00:00  2020-08-01 01:00:00
          5  2020-08-01 01:00:00    B      2 2020-08-01 00:00:00  2020-08-01 01:00:00
```

To get the final result, there is a need to:

- *reset_index(...)* - drop the first 2 levels of the index.
- *sort_index()* - sort rows by index.

The result is just as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Initial DataFrame**

```
print(df)
                  Hour Site
0  2020-01-08 00:00:00    A
1  2020-01-08 00:00:00    B
2  2020-01-08 00:00:00    C
3  2020-01-08 00:00:00    D
4  2020-01-08 01:00:00    A
5  2020-01-08 01:00:00    B
6  2020-01-08 01:00:00    E
7  2020-01-08 01:00:00    F
8  2020-01-08 02:00:00    A
9  2020-01-08 02:00:00    E
10 2020-01-08 03:00:00    C
11 2020-01-08 03:00:00    G
12 2020-01-08 04:00:00    X
13 2020-01-08 04:00:00    s
14 2020-01-08 23:00:00    G
15 2020-02-08 00:00:00    G
```

---

**My approach**

```
#if it is necesary
#df['Hour']=pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'])
#df=df.sort_values('Hour')

g=( df.groupby('Site')['Hour'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
      .groupby(df['Site']).cumsum() )

groups = df.groupby(['Site',g])['Hour']
new_df = df.assign(count = groups.transform('size'),
                   Period_start = groups.transform('first'),
                   Period_end = groups.transform('last'))

print(new_df)
```

---

**Output**

```
                  Hour Site  count        Period_start          Period_end
0  2020-01-08 00:00:00    A      3 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
1  2020-01-08 00:00:00    B      2 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 01:00:00
2  2020-01-08 00:00:00    C      1 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 00:00:00
3  2020-01-08 00:00:00    D      1 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 00:00:00
4  2020-01-08 01:00:00    A      3 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
5  2020-01-08 01:00:00    B      2 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 01:00:00
6  2020-01-08 01:00:00    E      2 2020-01-08 01:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
7  2020-01-08 01:00:00    F      1 2020-01-08 01:00:00 2020-01-08 01:00:00
8  2020-01-08 02:00:00    A      3 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
9  2020-01-08 02:00:00    E      2 2020-01-08 01:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
10 2020-01-08 03:00:00    C      1 2020-01-08 03:00:00 2020-01-08 03:00:00
11 2020-01-08 03:00:00    G      1 2020-01-08 03:00:00 2020-01-08 03:00:00
12 2020-01-08 04:00:00    X      1 2020-01-08 04:00:00 2020-01-08 04:00:00
13 2020-01-08 04:00:00    s      1 2020-01-08 04:00:00 2020-01-08 04:00:00
14 2020-01-08 23:00:00    G      1 2020-01-08 23:00:00 2020-01-08 23:00:00
15 2020-02-08 00:00:00    G      1 2020-02-08 00:00:00 2020-02-08 00:00:00
```

---

**If you want mask if count equal 1**

```
#if it is necesary
#df['Hour']=pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'])
#df=df.sort_values('Hour')

g=( df.groupby('Site')['Hour'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
      .groupby(df['Site']).cumsum() )

groups = df.groupby(['Site',g])['Hour']
new_df =( df.assign(count = groups.transform('size'))
            .assign(Period_start = lambda x: groups.transform('first')
                                                   .where(x['count'].gt(1)),
                   Period_end = lambda x: groups.transform('last')
                                                .where(x['count'].gt(1))) )
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
                  Hour Site  count        Period_start          Period_end
0  2020-01-08 00:00:00    A      3 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
1  2020-01-08 00:00:00    B      2 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 01:00:00
2  2020-01-08 00:00:00    C      1                 NaT                 NaT
3  2020-01-08 00:00:00    D      1                 NaT                 NaT
4  2020-01-08 01:00:00    A      3 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
5  2020-01-08 01:00:00    B      2 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 01:00:00
6  2020-01-08 01:00:00    E      2 2020-01-08 01:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
7  2020-01-08 01:00:00    F      1                 NaT                 NaT
8  2020-01-08 02:00:00    A      3 2020-01-08 00:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
9  2020-01-08 02:00:00    E      2 2020-01-08 01:00:00 2020-01-08 02:00:00
10 2020-01-08 03:00:00    C      1                 NaT                 NaT
11 2020-01-08 03:00:00    G      1                 NaT                 NaT
12 2020-01-08 04:00:00    X      1                 NaT                 NaT
13 2020-01-08 04:00:00    s      1                 NaT                 NaT
14 2020-01-08 23:00:00    G      1                 NaT                 NaT
15 2020-02-08 00:00:00    G      1                 NaT                 NaT
```

Comment: It was a mistake

Comment: I think so, so ask in comment :)