# Simplified pandas groupby aggregation for datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this pandas dataframe with a datetime, an integer, and a string column

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
data1 =  """Year        N   X
            2008-01-01  2   A
            2008-01-01  3   B
            2008-01-01  6   C
            2008-01-01  2   D
            2010-01-01  7   A
            2010-01-01  1   B
            2010-01-01  8   C
            2012-01-01  9   A
            2012-01-01  4   B
            2016-01-01  1   A"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=["Year"])
```

I can aggregate column `N` for count, min, and max simply as:

```
df1 = df.groupby("X")["N"].agg(Count="count", Min="min", Max="max").reset_index()
print(df1)

   X  Count  Min  Max
0  A      4    1    9
1  B      3    1    4
2  C      2    6    8
3  D      1    2    2
```

Is there a way to achieve the same for column `Year` only displaying the year?
I can do this in several steps:

```
g = df.groupby("X")["Year"]
df2 = g.agg(Count= "count").reset_index()
df2["Start_date"] = g.min().dt.year.values
df2["End_date"] = g.max().dt.year.values
print(df2)

   X  Count  Start_date  End_date
0  A      4        2008      2016
1  B      3        2008      2012
2  C      2        2008      2010
3  D      1        2008      2008
```

But a version similar to that above for `N`such as

```
df2 = df.groupby("X")["Year"].agg(Count="count", Min="min().dt.year.values", Max="max().dt.year.values").reset_index()
```

obviously does not work. Is there a simpler way to aggregate the first and last year in pandas groupby (apart from the obvious approach to first extract min/max dates as above, then convert the datetime columns into year columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `GroupBy.agg` with named aggregation?

```
df.assign(Year=pd.to_datetime(df['Year']).dt.year).groupby('X').agg(
    N=('N', 'count'), Start_date=('Year', 'first'), End_date=('Year', 'last'),)

   N  Start_date  End_date
X                         
A  4        2008      2016
B  3        2008      2012
C  2        2008      2010
D  1        2008      2008
```

If the dates aren't ascending, use `'min'` and `'max'` instead of `'first'` and `'last'`, respectively.

This way allows you to avoid using lambda expressions in the grouper (so this is quite performant). More on named aggregation can be found in my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300159/4909087).

Comment: I think you have the power to single-handedly close my question as a duplicate of a "named aggregation" question. It seems this is what it boils down to.

Comment: I personally think its fine to have more than one way to ask the same thing, especially if you've made an honest effort and are reaching out for help with the last mile. So I have no strong preference either way. But since you seem not to mind, and since the linked dupe has my answer anyway I think I'll go ahead and close it for ya :p

Answer (score 3):

- [named aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127632/how-to-use-named-aggregation)
- `lambda` function on date series

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Year        N   X
            2008-01-01  2   A
            2008-01-01  3   B
            2008-01-01  6   C
            2008-01-01  2   D
            2010-01-01  7   A
            2010-01-01  1   B
            2010-01-01  8   C
            2012-01-01  9   A
            2012-01-01  4   B
            2016-01-01  1   A"""), sep="\s+")
df.Year = pd.to_datetime(df.Year)

df = df.groupby("X").agg(N=("N","count"),
                    Start_date=("Year",lambda f: min(f.dt.year)),
                    End_date=("Year",lambda f: max(f.dt.year)))
```

| X | N | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 2008 | 2016 |
| B | 3 | 2008 | 2012 |
| C | 2 | 2008 | 2010 |
| D | 1 | 2008 | 2008 |

Comment: Nice. Never encountered named aggregation before.